# Scrolling within an elements causes troubles

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

HTML - Javascript - CSS3

i have a scrolling elements that contains texts.
When the user scroll using the side bar of the scroll , All buttons in my page will ignore the 1st click on them , u need to click a 2nd time to work.

i explain otherwise :

All my button are working fine and act with the 1st click on them (normal) .
But if you scroll an elements within the page , then the next click on any button will not work ... it's only when u click a 2nd time it works.

any help ? thx.

Comment: And exactly how are we supposed to diagnose code without seeing the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you scroll something will reinitialize like your elements so on scrolling they will disappear so you should reinitialize the controls it will work.
You can give few code you wrote which will make more clear to us.

Comment: the scorlling elements is a simple div with overflow set to auto .
the buttons are simple div scripted with on("mousedown",function(){})
using the Jquery 1.7.2 min .
after scrolling , on('mouseenter',fn) & on('mouseleave',fn) work fine , but the on('mousedown',fn) needs two clicks , as u said the 1st to reintialize , then 2nd takes effect .